# Angular SPA application make other URL to still have highlight Nav bar section based on URL number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an Angular SPA application in which which the main routing navigation is done I have it highlight the correct heading.

However I now need to have it highlight as Active when a specific link is clicked on the page ,  the specific URL i will know that it contains a "5"

Currently If this URL is hit

`http://srpdop03/doc-home/#/coordinators`

Then I highlights the navbar background with white color

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/coordinators')}"><a href="#/coordinators">Coordinators</a></li>
```

So on that Coordinator Page, when I click a News link the new URL is

`http://srpdop03/doc-home/#/tips/5?paginatePage=1`

Thus in this index.html SPA app , is there a way to easily read the URL and see perhaps this specific part of the URL

```
 /tips/5
```

Then to make the SAME  - coordinators navigation to be "active"  ?

The ng-controller code in  index.html currently looks like this

```
<div ng-controller="TopNavCtrl" class="navbar">
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav">
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/">DOC</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/supervisors')}" ng-if="user.groups.DOC_SUPERVISORS || user.groups.DOC_BACKUP_SUPERVISORS">
        <a href="#/supervisors">Supervisors</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/dispatchers')}"><a href="#/dispatchers">Dispatchers</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/coordinators')}"><a href="#/coordinators">Coordinators</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/reliability')}"><a href="#/reliability">Reliability</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/specialists')}"><a href="#/specialists">Specialists</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/mapping')}"><a href="#/mapping">Mapping</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/techs')}"><a href="#/techs">Cap Techs</a></li>
    <!--<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/applications')}"><a href="#/applications">BOA</a></li>-->
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/boa')}"><a href="#/boa">BOA</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav-right">
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/user')}" ng-show="isAdmin()">
        <a href="#/user"><b>{{ user.ntid }}</b></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}" ng-show="!isAdmin()">
        <a href="#/"><b>{{ user.ntid }}</b></a>
    </li>
    <!--<li>{{info.host}}</li>-->
  </ul>

</div>
```

THEN in  `app.js`

```
app.controller('TopNavCtrl', function ($scope, $http, UserService,  $location) {
$http.get('api/env')
.success(function (info) {
  $scope.info = info;
  UserService.get(function (err, user) {
    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        var active = (viewLocation === $location.path());
        //var active = $location.path().indexOf(viewLocation) == 0;  
        return active;
    };

    $scope.isAdmin = function () {
      return user.groups.WEB_ESO ||
             info.env === 'development'
    };
  });
});
```

});

I was looking at this article a bit 
http://webdesignerhut.com/active-class-navigation-menu/

this is jquery code though , and i'm not sure how to retrofit a custom lastIndexOf etc..

```
$(function() {
 var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
 $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
      $(this).addClass("active");
 })
 });
```

Comment: So would there be a good way to do this in index.html or should it be done in app.js  ?

Comment: I can see that the the URL is found within app.js  controller  

  `if ($location.path() === "/tips/5") {
     console.log('yes');
  }`

Comment: Do you happen to be using ui.router?

Comment: Of all the modules loaded, I see that   'ngRoute',
  'ui.sortable',   and 2 listed that could possibly answer your question.   I did google ui.router, but i don't know yet

Answer (score 0):

#### Add ui-router as a dependency.

ui-router is particularly good at showing active state in navigation menus. As well [documented here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active), ui router's [ui-sref-active](/questions/tagged/ui-sref-active) has a "primary use-case is to simplify the special appearance of navigation menus relying on ui-sref, by having the "active" state's menu button appear different, distinguishing it from the inactive menu items."

In your case i would consider doing something like this:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,
$urlRouterProvider,){

 add your routes here:
}]);


<ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item active">
    <a ui-sref="app.user({user: 'anyone'})" href="/users/anyone">anyone</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: well,  I don't know how to easily really add that to my code